# pandas filter and apply

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the following data frame (df):

```
Group Value
  A     1
  A     2
  A     3
  B    -1
  B     2
  B     3
```

I would like to convert all of group B to negative values if they arent already (ie multiply by -1).

```
df[df['group'] == 'B', 'value'].apply(... if value less than 0 then -1*value)
```

Please let me know the correct way to go about this in pandas framework. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [85]: df.loc[df.Group.eq('B') & df.Value.gt(0), 'Value'] *= -1

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
  Group  Value
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     B     -1
4     B     -2
5     B     -3
```

Comment: nice answer! Can you pl tell me why doesn't df.loc[(df.Group == 'B' & df.Value > 0), 'Value']*= -1 work? I was getting an error, TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [int64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: @A-Za-z, thank you! It's a [Pandas & Python precedence problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40578010/5741205). Try this instead: `df.loc[(df.Group == 'B') & (df.Value > 0), 'Value']`

Comment: Ah! I feel so dumb:)

Comment: @MaxU nice other answer too

Comment: @A-Za-z I feel so dumb too sometimes. But I also have moments of brilliance. Net net, it probably averages out.  Go ahead and feel dumb this time :-). It won't change the fact that you clearly aren't.

Answer (score 2):

A different way using `mask` and `np.sign`

```
df.assign(Value=df.Value.mask(df.Group == 'B', -np.sign(df.Value) * df.Value))

  Group  Value
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     B     -1
4     B     -2
5     B     -3
```