# Python3: Creating two Masks vs. One In-line mask -> Different Results?

Tags: python, pandas

I came across an interesting problem and I'm hoping someone will be able to explain it to me.  I run the code below and Method One fails, while method two runs perfectly.  Anyone have an idea why?  Thanks!

## Method 1

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1, 2, 3, 'NaN' ], 'y' : [4, 'NaN', 5, 6], 'z' : ["Boy", "Boy", "Girl", "Boy"]})
df.x.notnull() & df.z=='Boy' 
#Throws Error
```

## Method 2

```
mask1 = df.x.notnull()
mask2 = df.z=='Boy'
mask1 & mask2
#Works
```

Comment: you may want to check [this answer with some examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40578010/5741205)

Comment: Thanks @MaxU...Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with operator precedence. This will work:

```
df.x.notnull() & (df.z == 'Boy')
```

However your original code was interpreted as:

```
(df.x.notnull() & df.z) == 'Boy'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This makes sense and reminds me the importance to read the order of operations again for Python.