# Writing to multiple columns in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read one csv file and write specific rows of that file into another file.

The code runs fine, but the output is not formatted properly:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

f = open("output.csv", 'w')
sys.stdout = f

df = pd.read_csv('original_file.csv', low_memory=False)

print df[(df.name == 'fullName')]
print df[(df.name == 'LastName')]

f.close()
```

In the original file there are multiple columns, all filled with strings. I want to print every row where the `name` column equals `fullName` and `LastName`. However `output.csv` has all of the data crammed into a single column.

I'm doing all of this on Ubuntu using Vim. I don't know if that would make a difference.

How do I get the output data to write to its corresponding column in    `output.csv`?

Comment: Any reason not to use `to_csv` method ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: `print df[(df.name == 'fullName')|(df.name == 'LastName')]`

Comment: @AdrienMatissart I had tried using that before, but I was not able to search for the values within the cells e.g. `fullName` and such. I'm sure there is a way, but I'm not familiar enough with pandas to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('original_file.csv', low_memory=False) # read dataframe
new_df = df.loc[(df.name == 'fullName')|(df.name == 'LastName')] # select rows with name == fullname or lastname
new_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False) # write to csv
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a perfect solution to my question. I've been struggling with this for almost a week now.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't wait for an entire week next time to seek help :)

Comment: Haha. I've been asking all week. You're the first person that seemed to understand the question. My questions would get downvoted and marked as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

***The last line of my solution is wrong. Because of operator precedence rules, the boolean array is being compared to a dataframe column, which is not what one might be looking for.***

What you are doing essentially is you write two columns sequentially. Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = pd.read_csv('original_file.csv', low_memory=False)

# write select columns of the dataframe to output.csv
df[df['name'] == 'fullName' | df['name'] == 'LastName' ].to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: `df[df['name'] == 'fullName' | df['name'] == 'LastName' ]` will not work as expected - you need to add parentheses. PS it wasn't me who has downvoted your answer...

Comment: @MaxU Thank you for your comment!

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578010/5741205), which explains why it will not work as expected...

Comment: @MaxU I tested it myself and included a comment in my answer. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: why don't you want to correct it? There is a bit shorter version: `df[df['name'].isin(['fullName','LastName'])].to_csv('output.csv')`

Comment: @MaxU If I amend it, it will be a duplicate of an existing correct answer. Leaving it as is with the comment included would make it be of greater educational value to anyone who sees it. :)